# How to change variable name color?

Tags: pycharm

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        byte_string = 'newline:\n also newline:\x0a'
```

In PyCharm, how do I change the color of variables like "byte_string" in the example above?
I don't see any place to change this in the "Python" section of the color settings.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unbelievable but true, I was answered by Pycharm staff that it is NOT possible to set custom variable color.
Please all vote on: 
 https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-8246

Comment: It has been almost 2 years and the issue still remains open. Wow.

Comment: this is no longer true with newer versions of pycharm, see the answer below about semantic highlighting. just change all the colors to a single value to have a consistent variable color.

Comment: @Enigma22134 it's not completely solved... the semantic highlighting setting lumps function parameters together with local variables

Comment: True, but I think distinguishing between a local variable and a parameter variable is a feature on top of highlighting variable names.

Answer (score 9):

PyCharm 2017.1 has "semantic highlighting". Give it a try.

It looks like this:

[image: semantic highlighting settings]

Comment: It seems that this overrides the parameter color setting, so parameters and local variables use the same spectrum. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

To change the default color of variables in PyCharm (4.5.3, to be precise), take the following steps:

1. Open the **Preferences** window.
2. In the left sidebar, click on the node labeled **Editor**.
3. Under **Editor**, click on the node labeled **Colors & Fonts**, then the sub-node, **Language Defaults**.
4. If you're using a default color scheme, click the button labeled **Save As**, as PyCharm won't let you overwrite built-in color schemes.
5. In the center of the window, you'll see a list of language elements. Based on your example, it looks like you want to change the appearance of *local* variables, so scroll to the item labeled **Local variable**, and click on it.

If you'd also like to change the color of *global* variables, or even of all identifiers, just scroll to the item labeled **Global variables** or **Identifiers**, as appropriate, and follow steps 5-7.

**TL;DR**: Edit local variable colors at **Preferences > Editor > Colors & Fonts > Language Defaults > Local variable.**

Comment: Thanks, I did what you said, and set the variables to red color, but as you can see on the new image I attached above, it didn't change the color of the variable 'far' in the editor window.

Comment: @RobertBrax This may sound stupid, but did you remember to click *Apply*?

Comment: @RobertBrax That's very peculiar - you may have come across a bug. I'm getting the same results as you are. I have RubyMine and IntelliJ installed as well, and, in each of those, there's no issue, by in PyCharm it doesn't seem to work, other than by changing the default color for all text.

Answer (score 0):

The 2018 versions of Pycharm now support semantic highlighting, which applies colors to local and global variables.

Under 
   `file, settings`

Navigate to
   `Editor->Color Scheme->Language Defaults->Symantic higlighting` to change the colors that the editor uses for variables.

You'll probably need to save your own custom theme as mentioned in the Tutleman's comment. By default Pycharm gives a range of 5 colors to use, if you want all your variables to be the same color, then you can set all 5 colors to the same color.

---

edit: I undeleted this because it solved what I was looking for when you found question. I'm not sure why you decided to delete it? I believe this will solve the problem people are searching about when they find your post.