# How to change variable name color in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java

How do I change the color of the variable names in Intellij IDEA for Java?
e.g. the "foo" in:

```
int foo;
```

Comment: This is for PyCharm, but since they're both JetBrains IDEs, they should be similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31705927/how-to-change-variable-name-color

Comment: @GalaxyCat105 I looked at it before posting, it doesnt help

Answer (score 3):

Go to `File` > `Settings` > `Editor` > `Color Scheme` > `Language Defaults`. There you can re-define your colors for all types of variables.

[image: lang defs]

Comment: I already did all of that stuff, but i cant change the variable name.

Comment: What do you mean by "change the variable name"

Comment: Do you mean you can't change the foreground and background values?

Comment: I mean I can't change the text color of the variable name, so it's always a dull grey.

Comment: Can you tick that box on the right, that says `Inherit values from`, does that help with the problem?

Comment: thanks but I just changed my color scheme and that worked.