# Pycharm Syntax Highlighting not working properly for variables

Tags: pycharm

I am using the newest Pycharm Professional Release 2023.3.2 (same issue with 2023.3.1)

If i define a variable within a function, the highlighting for this variable works. If i define it outside a function, it does not work. I've tried several color schemes (dark, monokai, and community ones) and none of them highlight the variable outside a function.

Is this expected or am i missing something?.. According to the color scheme preview, these variables should get highlighted.

[[image: highlighting1]

Preview:

[image: preview]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the expected behavior of PyCharm.

In the preview, `x` represents a local variable.
[image]
Notice that when I select **Local variables** in the settings, a rectangle surrounds `x`. (This description might seem awkward, but that's how it works).

In your code, `five` is not a local variable.

You can alter the color of global variables by enabling **semantic highlighting**. However, I think you cannot modify other settings for global variables. (See [How to change variable name color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31705927/how-to-change-variable-name-color))